# re to identify range from string

Tags: python, regex, list, parsing

How to write and Regular expression to get list from string like if we have string:

```
value = '88-94'
value = '88 to 94'
value = '88'
value = '88-94, 96-108'
```

outcome should be:

```
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
[88]
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]
```

Programming language is python2.7

Here is a working Solution for python2.7 and regex but do have to check for last case having single value as separate case:

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.match(r"(?:(?P<digits>\d+).(?P<digits>\d+))", "88-94")
>>> a = m.captures("digits")
>>> a
['88', '94']
>>> m = regex.match(r"(?:(?P<digits>\d+).(?P<digits>\d+))", "88 94")
>>> a = m.captures("digits")
>>> a
['88', '94']
>>> range(int(a[0]), int(a[1])+1)
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
>>>
```

Here is a solution which address above cases but what about 88-94, 96-98 etc

```
>>> import re
>>> a = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', '88-94'))
>>> range(a[0], a[-1]+1)
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
>>> a = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', '88 94'))
>>> range(a[0], a[-1]+1)
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
>>> a = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', '88'))
>>> range(a[0], a[-1]+1)
[88]
>>>
```

Solution that cover almost all Cases:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', '88-94, 96-108'))
>>> c = zip(a[::2], a[1::2])
>>> [m for k in [range(i,j+1) for i, j in c] for m in k]
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]
>>> a = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', '88-94, 96-108, 125 129'))
>>> c = zip(a[::2], a[1::2])
>>> [m for k in [range(i,j+1) for i, j in c] for m in k]
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129]
>>> a = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', '88-94, 96-108, 125 129, 132 to 136'))
>>> c = zip(a[::2], a[1::2])
>>> [m for k in [range(i,j+1) for i, j in c] for m in k]
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136]
>>>
```

Can anyone suggest reason to downvote or vote for close?

Any Help will be appreciated and can anyone suggest how to update question I am not asking for alternate solutions as I know how to split and loop even re to strip digits and loop, my question is how to do it with re in single statement if possible? Answer could be no but not question as Off-topic.

Comment: `start, stop = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', re.sub(r'^(\d+)$', r'\1-\1', value))); print range(start, stop+1)`   (2 statements)

Comment: Why do you want to do it as a single statement? Do it the way its legible and makes sense to you. [Explicit is better than implicit; and simple is better than complex](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: I am looking for good input from gru's on how we can do this to cater as much as possible cases using RE my purpose is to understand can we generate series using python re or regex library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def get_numbers(value):
    value = re.sub(r'^(\d+)$', r'\1-\1', value) # '88' -> '88-88'
    start, stop = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', value))
    return range(start, stop+1)

print get_numbers('88-94')
print get_numbers('88 to 94')
print get_numbers('88')
```

output:

```
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
[88]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
range(*map(int,mystring.split("-")))
```

No need for regex

Comment: `int` is missing: `range(*map(int, mystring.split("-")))`.

Comment: And when `mystring = '10'`, it will produce `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment, but won't this fail when there are multiple `-`, as in `"3-4-5-6-7"?

Comment: @SteveP. Is that a valid range? OP wants to identify range from string.

Comment: @thefourtheye No, but it's a valid string...this works assuming correct, two input number strings, but fails for everything else.

Comment: It is not valid with second case. secondly re is needed to identify cases like 88-94, 88 94 etc

Comment: Another problem, Even after adding `int`: this code produces `[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93]` for '88-94' instead of `[88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]`.

Comment: What about "to" instead of "-"?

Comment: lol then just split on "to"... yeah I meant to have the int in there... thats what I get for using SO at the bar on my phone ...